# How collateral is distributed to token side (L or S) in perpetual pool?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink, defi, liquidity-provider

I am trying to implement a distribution of collateral deposited in the pool but I am not getting how it should be distributed in the perpetual pool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are asking about how the shares are calculated in perpetual pools/vaults based on your collateral. I would recommend you to check the [ERC4626 implementation from OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC4626.sol) to get glue on how internal math works.